# ¿Como Contar los espacios en blanco en una cadena de String usando Recursividad en java?

Tags: java

Muy buenas colegas, tengo un problema en el cual consiste en contar los espacios vacíos de una cadena de String, ejemplo:

**String text = "Estructura De Datos";** //Espacios en blanco = 2

Para realizar este programa en java es necesario utilizar recursividad, es un tema que recién estoy aprendiendo y el cual aun no me queda muy claro.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias de antemano a todos:).

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow en Español**! Las preguntas que buscan ayudas con tareas deben mostrar el trabajo realizado y enfocarse en problemas concretos, NUNCA solicitar que las hagan por tí (sino no van a ser bien recibidas por la comunidad). Puedes pasarte por el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que aprendas como funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Enlces de interés: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int ContarEspacios(string texto, int index)
{
    int cont = 0;

    if(index == texto.Length)
return cont;

if(texto.charAt(index) ==  ' ')
{
    cont++;
}
index++;
return cont + ContarEspacios(texto, index);
}
```

La función recibe dos parámetros el texto y el índice que es la posición desde donde se va a recorrer la cadena que empezaría en 0 ya que la posición primera de los string en Java es 0

La variable cont es la q contará la cantidad de espacios qué hay en el texto
Lo primero q se hace es preguntar si el índice es igual al tamaño de la cadena de ser cierto esto significa que el algoritmo llego a su fin de lo contrario se comprueba si el carácter actual es un espacio y seguiría invocándose la función recursivamwnte

Para llamar la función sería

```
int x = ContarEspacios(palabra, 0);
```

Comment: En Java no puedes acceder a los caracteres de un `String` usando notación de arreglos. Por lo tanto esta sintaxis no es válida y provoca un error de compilación: `texto[index]`. Por otra parte, las preguntas que buscan ayudas con tareas deben mostrar el trabajo realizado y enfocarse en problemas/dudas concretos. Te sugiero no responder a este tipo de preguntas para que evites valoraciones negativas a tus respuestas.